# State provided through react context is reset after changing URL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state, react-context

I am using NextJs and have a state that I provide through react context. The state is an access token for a websdk and I need to get this access token from my backend first before I can initialize the sdk.

The react context I defined is this:

```
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

export type WebSDKContextType = {
  accessToken: string
  setAccessToken: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}

export const WebSDKContext = createContext<WebSDKContextType>({ accessToken: '', setAccessToken: () => { } });
```

In my `_app.tsx` I initialize it with:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('')
  console.log('Access Token a:', accessToken)
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <WebSDKContext.Provider value={{ accessToken, setAccessToken }}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </WebSDKContext.Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

On my main page I have a form that the user fills out and when submitted will request an `accessToken` this same action also forwards them to the page where they use the websdk. The respective `onSubmit` and `onClick` funcitons are:

```
//Form on submit:
async function startWebSDK(address: string) {
    // Request the token from the backend
    const res = await createApplicant({ variables: { address } })
    console.log(res)
    // If received the token set the state
    if (res.data && res.data.createApplicant.applicant) {
      console.log('setAccessToken')
      setAccessToken(res.data.createApplicant.applicant.sumsub_token)
    } else {
      console.log('Did not get token')
    }
  }

//Submitt button onClick
onClick={() => router.push('/kyc')}
```

This opens the kyc page where I read the accessToken and initialize the WebSDK

```
const kyc: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { accessToken } = useContext(WebSDKContext)
  console.log('Access Token b:', accessToken)
  if (accessToken === '') {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <WebSdk
        accessToken={accessToken}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Problem:** I can follow this flow (enter data & get accessToken -> redirect to kyc page) and everything works. However when I then change the URL and go back to the main page, the accessToken is reset to `''`. Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

---

**Edit:** When I use the go-back and go-forward functionality of the browser the state remains intact.